# Python: putting elements into proper interval

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array denoting intervals

```
 a=[1,3,5,7,9]
```

I have another array

```
 p=[2.5,7.9,6,5.7]
```

I want to distribute the elements of `p` into the intervals. The resulting array will be the lower bounds of the intervals.

For example, take the first element, it lies in the first interval `1<2.5<3`, so I want to construct a new array with the same length as that of `p` whose first element will be the lower bound of the interval, so `1`, likewise for all other elements. The result should be `[1,7,5,5]`

This is what I have so far for the first elements of the arrays, but it doesn't return anything, the code seems to run forever

```
 pl= p[:,0]
 al=np.zeros(len(pl))
 i=0
 j=0
 while i<len(a):
       while j<len(pl):
            if  pl[i][np.logical_and(a[j],a[j+1])]:
                al[i]=a[i]
                j+=1
            i+=1     

 print al
```

Edit 1: Based on the responses I made the following change to the code

```
  al=np.zeros(len(pl))
  for i in range(len(pl)):
        for j in range(len(a)-1):
                 **if  pl[i][np.logical_and(a[j],a[j+1])]:**
                        al[i]=a[j]
```

**EDIT (answer):** I had a very misleading understanding about the `np.logical` operator, all I wanted to do was to have a compound conditional statement `a[j]<= pl[i]<a[j+1]`, which is exactly what I should have in my code. I have added this to the answer below. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: It seems that your code gets stuck in the second while loop and increases value of i forever without checking the outer while condition. This is because it never increases value of j and so the condition of the second loop is true forever. By the way, your Description of the problem is really unclear, you may consider clarifying what you are really looking for

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for, I mean logic of your code. But the reason for why the code above doesn't work is what I commented above

Comment: Is it good enough now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   while j<len(pl):
        if  pl[i][np.logical_and(a[j],a[j+1])]:
            p_new[i]=a[i]
            j+=1    <-------##Problem lies here
```

So, I think what's happening is you are getting stuck in your while loop. 
If your condition is not true, J doesn't increment and it just reruns infinitely (your i also would increment towards infinity).

It would seem that you know how many times you want your loop to iterate (len(pl)), so a for loop might be a better tool:

```
for i in range(len(a))
    for j in range(len(pl)):
        if  pl[i][np.logical_and(a[j],a[j+1])]:
            p_new[i]=a[i]
```

Edit: based on the edit and response I believe the following is what you are after:

```
a = [boundaries]
p = [p]# this can be anything
for i in p:
    for bound in a:
        if i > bound:
            pass
        else:
            p1.append(bound)
```

Comment: I understand your logic, but there seems to be something wrong, I am getting the wrong result. Please see the edits that I made.

Answer (score 1):

Use code like below :

```
a=[1,3,5,7,9]
pl=[2.5,7.9,6,5.7] 

for i in range(len(pl)):
         for j in range(len(a)-1):
                if  a[j]<= pl[i]<a[j+1]:
                      pl[i]=a[j]  
print  pl
```

Comment: I think you are going about this in a very... complicated way. Why are you using p1 as a bound for your intervals?

See my answer for a wrking version